# Intellij difference between effective pom and dependencyies pop up

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, effective-pom

I opened the dependencies pop-up in pom.xml file by

right click anywhere in pom.xml file -> maven -> show dependencies pop up

Also I opened the effective pom by
right click anywhere in pom.xml file -> maven -> show effective pom

I noticed that there are differences between 2 dependencies (e.g there are a lot of dependencies in effective pom which are not present in pop-up) Any idea why did this happen ?

Comment: Can you share any project example to show it?

Answer (score 0):

Every **application pom** file (the one that we explicitly defined in the project ) inherits from a default **super pom** file. For example, here is the [super pom file for Maven 3.0.4](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html).

When you view the *effective pom* of a project, you can see inside it all the configurations of the project, which comes from the default settings in the **super pom** and the configurations defined in our **application pom**. Hence, you will find in the *effective pom* the complete list of dependencies of the project coming from  **both the super pom and the application pom**. Contrarily, the *show dependecies pop up* only includes the configurations defined in the **application pom** and their dependencies, hence the difference between the two.